# TicTacToe board check

Tags: xcode, command-line

I'm creating a TicTacToe game using command line in Xcode.  I've got everything working properly except I can't figure out how to avoid a player from taking another players spot.  So if player one chooses spot [1][1], if either player enters spot [1][1] throughout the game they will get "Invalid entry, please try again" and they will have to choose another spot.  Any suggestions?

```
- (void) getChoice1
{
    do
    {
        if (player == 1 && winner == 0 && turns < 9)
        {
            do {
            //player 1's input
            NSLog(@"Player 1, please choose a cell.");
            NSLog(@"Enter row number(1, 2, or 3).");
            scanf("%ld", &row);
            } while ((row != 1 && row != 2  && row != 3));

        do{
        NSLog(@"Enter column number(1, 2, or 3).");
        scanf("%ld", &column);
        } while ((column != 1 && column != 2  && column != 3));


        //decrement players input -1
        row--;
        column--;

        //ensure spot is unselected
        if (arr[row][column] == 1 || arr[row][column] == 2) {
            NSLog(@"Invalid entry, try another spot");

            [self getChoice1];
        }
        else
        {

            //add input to board
            arr [row][column] = 1;

            //display updated board
            [self showBoard];

            //switch players
            player = 2;

            //add a turn
            turns++;

            //check for winner
            [self checkWinner];
        }
    }    
} while (turns < 9 && winner == 0 );
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a friend I realized I have to restructure the method completely.  Here's my working answer.

```
do
    {
        if (winner == 0 && turns < 9)
        {
            do {
            //player 1's input
            if (player == 1) {
                NSLog(@"Player 1, please choose a cell.");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Player 2, please choose a cell.");
            }
            NSLog(@"Enter row number(1, 2, or 3).");
            scanf("%ld", &row);
            } while ((row != 1 && row != 2  && row != 3));
            do{
            NSLog(@"Enter column number(1, 2, or 3).");
            scanf("%ld", &column);
            } while ((column != 1 && column != 2  && column != 3));
            //decrement players input -1
            row--;
            column--;
           //add input to board
            if (arr [row][column] == 0) {
                arr [row][column] = player;
                if (player == 1) {
                    player = 2;
                } else {
                    player = 1;
                }
                //display updated board
                [self showBoard];
                //add a turn
                turns++;
            } else {
                NSLog (@"Cell already used pick a different cell.");
            }            
            //check for winner
            [self checkWinner];
        }
    } while (turns < 9 && winner == 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make userInteraction disabled for that block.

For example if block1 is touched, make :

```
block1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Once, game is complete, make userInteractionEnabled fro all blocks again to YES.

This will work as I have also made one similar game.

In case of command line , you can set some variables for example if for x set 1, for 0 set 2, for no play set 0.

Then, once someone new press there check for 1 and 2 and do the required

Comment: @samkit, Anil is correct.  It's in command line.  Maybe I wasn't clear.  I've created a board which I'm calling after each player's turn is complete.  Within each turn, if a player chooses a spot that has already been chosen they need to be told to choose another spot.

Comment: @SamkitJain, I've changed my code to show what I'm trying to do, however it doesn't work.  I'm guessing it's because of the if/else statement.  I've added the if/else statement to ensure the spot that player 1 has chosen hasn't been selected previously. Why doesn't this work and how do I correct it?

Comment: I saw your code...there is some issue with your loop..i guess your getChoice1 is recursively called...you should use break for that....`while (turns < 9 && winner == 0 );`  this line also sould not be there...show your full code ..then i can help